# JavaFX: ESC key press on secondary stage NOT creating a new Alert Dialog

Tags: java, javafx, dialog

**UPDATE #2**

Hi guys, lemme break down my thoughts with you.

---

### Current setup:

- a primaryStage with a button (called `rootButton`) to open a secondaryStage.
- a secondaryStage with a button (called `closeButton`) to close this secondaryStage.
- `closeButton.setCancelButton(true);` to make ESC key press on the secondaryStage fire the `closeButton`.

---

### Needed functionality:

- press ESC key on *secondaryStage* should popup an Alert dialog to
  ask me whether I really want to close the *secondaryStage*. <<<
  **How to implement?**

---

### Results of running current code:

1. the Alert dialog **doesn't show** when I hit the ESC key on the
   secondaryStage
2. command line shows: **"Cancel was pressed"**.

Therefore somehow the closeButton skips the Alert dialog popup, instead it leads directly to

```
if (result.get() == ButtonType.CANCEL) {
    System.out.println("Cancel was pressed.");
}
```

So could it be possible that the ESC key event is passed down from the secondaryStage to the Alert dialog? If that is the case, **how** and **where** do I properly consume this key event on the Alert dialog?

---

the current code (formatted with the help of GoXr3Plus):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Closing extends Application {

  // handle primaryStage
  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
     Button rootButton = new Button("show dialog");

     // rootButton
     rootButton.setOnAction(ac -> {

        // CloseButton
        Button closeButton = new Button("Close");
        closeButton.setCancelButton(true); // make this cancel button
        closeButton.setOnAction(a -> {

            // Initialize the alert
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "You really want to quit?");
            // Show the alert
            alert.showAndWait().ifPresent(result -> {
                if (result == ButtonType.OK)
                    System.out.println("OK was pressed.");
                else if (result == ButtonType.CANCEL)
                    System.out.println("Cancel was pressed.");
            });

            closeButton.getScene().getWindow().hide();
        });

        StackPane dialogPane = new StackPane(closeButton);

        Stage secondaryStage = new Stage();
        secondaryStage.setScene(new Scene(dialogPane, 200, 200));
        secondaryStage.showAndWait();
    });

    StackPane rootPane = new StackPane(rootButton);

    Scene scene = new Scene(rootPane, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

Comment: Check if it enters the onAction(...) using a System.out.println("Entered on Action method")..

Comment: DVarga and GoXr3Plus, thank both of you for your advice. I will try to give you guys more details after I have tried out your suggestion.

Comment: @GoXr3Plus Hi guys, I just updated my code. I am pretty new to stackoverflow but somehow I just can't get along with their code inserter. It is really a pain to work with. Anyways please have a short look, thanks!

Comment: @Chiggiddi, When I ran your code (after adding the requisite imports), it appears to run as expected. When I press escape on the secondary dialog, the `Alert` dialog appears, and I click OK, and the Alert and the secondary dialog disappear. 

Now, with that said, it would seem to me that clicking cancel on the Alert dialog should not close the underlying dialog. In that case you'll have to move the `closeButton.getScene().getWindow().hide();` inside the `if (result.get() == ButtonType.OK)` construct.

Comment: @RonSiven
Hi Ron, thanks for sticking around with me. Now I finally get that I didn't express myself clear enough in previous posts.
Let me explain that the functionality I need is to be able to press the ESC key (while in secondary stage) to open an Alert dialog which asks me whether I really want to close this secondaryStage. With the current code when I press ESC on the secondaryStage, there is no Alert dialog showing and the subsequent command line shows: "Cancel was pressed". The Alert dialog does only show when I mouseclick on the closeButton on secondaryStage.

Comment: @RonSiven
So could it be possible that the ESC key event is passed down from the secondaryStage to the Alert dialog? If that is the case, how and where do I properly consume this key event on the Alert dialog?

Comment: @Chiggiddi, It's no problem. I was with you from the beginning in understanding that the escape key on the secondary dialog was your focus. The question I have is, are you actually running the code you posted here? Because, when I run that code, the escape key works for me. It fires the desired event, and the Alert dialog is presented for me to select OK or Cancel. If you are _not_ running the code you have posted, I would assert that your posted code does demonstrate your issue. If you are running the code you have posted, I don't know what to tell you. Because it works for me.

Comment: @RonSiven Hi Ron, aw that is a bummer. But since this code works for you, it must mean that the code is good. So there might a conflict with my my jdk version. May I ask you what version of Oracle JDK you are running successfully with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SOLVED:

as Ron has pointed out this code is running fine. I updated to the current version of Java **JDK 1.8.0_91** and now the desired ESC key press does open a new dialog! Thanks everyone for your input!

Answer (score 0):

You may have to post all of your code or post an [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because the code you've already posted totally works for me. It almost seems as if you are somehow pressing escape twice in quick succession.

Try changing your `setOnAction` method to the following, and check standard out for the output.

```
btnCancel.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    alert.setContentText("You really want to quit?");
    Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
    if (result.isPresent()) {
        if (result.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
            System.out.println("OK was pressed.");
        }
        if (result.get() == ButtonType.CANCEL) {
            System.out.println("Cancel was pressed.");
        }
    }
    primaryStage.close();
});
```

Comment: Hi Ron, thanks a lot for your reply. I updated my code and inserted your suggestion. Please have a look when you have some time to spare. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't compile so i modified it to look better and added some comments.Let me know if it does what you want:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Closing extends Application {

  // handle primaryStage
  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
     Button rootButton = new Button("show dialog");

     // rootButton
     rootButton.setOnAction(ac -> {

        // CloseButton
        Button closeButton = new Button("Close");
        closeButton.setCancelButton(true); // make this cancel button
        closeButton.setOnAction(a -> {

            // Initialize the alert
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "You really want to quit?");
            // Show the alert
            alert.showAndWait().ifPresent(result -> {
                if (result == ButtonType.OK)
                    System.out.println("OK was pressed.");
                else if (result == ButtonType.CANCEL)
                    System.out.println("Cancel was pressed.");
            });

            closeButton.getScene().getWindow().hide();
        });

        StackPane dialogPane = new StackPane(closeButton);

        Stage secondaryStage = new Stage();
        secondaryStage.setScene(new Scene(dialogPane, 200, 200));
        secondaryStage.showAndWait();
    });

    StackPane rootPane = new StackPane(rootButton);

    Scene scene = new Scene(rootPane, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for taking your time. Indeed your formatting looks better! I will update my code with your suggested formatting. The reason for not compiling might be that I was frustrated with adding the imports. Either I am too dumb or the code insert functionality of stackoverflow just isn't that user-friendly.

Comment: @Chiggiddi Check this about formatting stackoveflow code :http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Nice, that is a really a good manual! Thanks a ton, this will really help me with future posts! Cheers mate!

Comment: old school is simply the BEST!